# Dexopt failed on a very big APK (Out-of-order method_idx) when dex.force.jumbo=true

Tags: android, adt, dex, dexopt

I have a very big Android project with a multiple, big, 3rd party jars (as Android Libraries).
I believe I've hit a Dex's max number of method limitation (compiling via eclipse):

> [2012-11-18 02:28:45 - Find In Files] Dx processing classes.dex...
>   [2012-11-18 02:28:48 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 66774 into a non-jumbo instruction!
>   [2012-11-18 02:28:48 - Find In Files] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 66774 into a non-jumbo instruction!

Taking advantage of SDK tools 21 (platform tools 16), I therefore, edited my main project project.properties to set `dex.force.jumbo=true`.
The flag allowed to me generate the APK. But I couldn't install it properly (on physical and emulator alike). There seems to be a dex optimizer failure:

> 11-18 20:11:05.338: I/PackageManager(103): Running dexopt on: com.mypackage.myapp
>   11-18 20:11:08.577: E/dalvikvm(868): Out-of-order method_idx: 0x2ae0 then 0x1
>   11-18 20:11:08.577: E/dalvikvm(868): Trouble with item 1544 @ offset 0xf7ae24
>   11-18 20:11:08.577: E/dalvikvm(868): Swap of section type 2006 failed
>   11-18 20:11:08.577: E/dalvikvm(868): ERROR: Byte swap + verify failed
>   11-18 20:11:08.597: E/dalvikvm(868): Optimization failed
>   11-18 20:11:08.597: W/installd(39): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.mypackage.myapp-1.apk' --- status=0xff00, process failed
>   11-18 20:11:08.597: E/installd(39): dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.mypackage.myapp-1.apk@classes.dex' res = 65280
>   11-18 20:11:08.697: W/PackageManager(103): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.mypackage.myapp-1.apk
>   11-18 20:11:09.018: D/dalvikvm(103): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1698K, 13% free 17034K/19463K, paused 7ms+135ms
>   11-18 20:11:09.068: D/AndroidRuntime(780): Shutting down VM

Am I trying to use the `dex.force.jumbo` flag for a purpose it was not intended for, or is this error unpredictable?
If so, is there a better strategy to generate a project that includes a very big number of classes/methods?

Comment: from the docs, dex.force.jumbo is only used to allow larger number of strings

Answer (score 8):

The 64K methods limit is a Dex format limitation (it uses 2 bytes to lookup a method).
Nandeesh comment's points out that jumbo solves string only, not methods.

**Alternatives** I tried/considered (brace yourselves, they all suck):
 1. **Do It Yourself** - Throw away the fattest 3rd party libraries and write the exact parts of its functionality yourself. This is the approach I ended up taking, as I realized I'm including a lot of code for a small functionality.
 2. [**Custom class loading in Dalvik**](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html) - Compile a separate Dex and load it on runtime. Cons: cumbersome, requires reflection.
 3. **Code Pruning** - Turn on verbose class loading, run the app and try to remove 3rd party libraries, or parts of the library that are not really used. Cons: time consuming, error prone as classes are dynamically loaded.
 4. **Divide And Concur** - Package 3rd party libraries in a separate process (a service). This service will provide the 3rd party libraries functionality. Perform calls on this service from your main program.

I believe that it's a case of *640k ought to be enough for anybody* OR *No way will have this on every 2nd phone in the planet* on the part of Dalvik's early design team.

If you want to read more or simply cry out load to Google, I've created this defect: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40409

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem. finally I found it may caused by multiple methods in same name, for example, doSomething(List list); and doSomething(List list); compiler says no errors, but it can't install to my device. So please check your methods with same name.