# Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 66713 into a non-jumbo instruction

Tags: android

When i try to run my project then console displays this type of message:
Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 66713 into a non-jumbo instruction

Comment: possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439882/android-error-in-eclipse-unable-to-execute-dex-cannot-merge-new-index-65799-i and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556360/dexopt-failed-on-a-very-big-apk-out-of-order-method-idx-when-dex-force-jumbo-t

Comment: @Patashu i tried this one but i couldn't solve this error.